# On WordPress.org Plugin repository, Last Updated Date doesn't match with Plugin Version Update Date

Tags: plugins, updates, wordpress.org

I have been going through the Plugin lists on all my client sites, looking for Plugins that haven't been updated by Plugin Authors. Every time we update a Plugin on a website, we note the date in our documentation. In the process, I have noticed a strange disagreement: on WordPress.org Plugin repository, **Last Updated** Date doesn't match with the Plugin's Version Update Date.

For example, in our documentation, a plugin named [Category Post](https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-posts) shows that the last update to version **4.9.13** was done on **9/29/2021**. The date here would cause this to be marked as a plugin that might need to be replaced, because it looks like it's a plugin that isn't being maintained.

But, when I went to WordPress.org (on February 2023) to check on the plugin, it says **Last Updated: 1 month ago**, to that same version number (4.9.13)!

Any clue as to what is happening?

Comment: Can you provide links to some of those plugins? I'm not sure, but it could be possible that a plugin author updated plugin files without updating the version number. If such is the case, then the plugin source code and log should reveal it.

Comment: The plugin I reference above is Category Post Widget. If I hadn't taken the extra step of checking WordPress.org, I would have replaced it.

If that is the case, then it is the change in version number that triggers the WordPress Dashboard to indicate that updates are needed.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-posts/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the [Category Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-posts/#developers) Plugin's **Changelog** on WordPress.org (on the `Development` tab). I'm providing the screenshot below:

[image: Category Posts Plugin change log]

You'll notice that version `4.9.13` was indeed updated on JULY 22 2021.

> 4.9.13 – JULY 22 2021
>
> Fixed Line number with WordPress 5.8

However, on the right side it shows: `Last updated: 1 month ago`.

This last update doesn't refer to updates to the plugin version itself, rather updated information on wordpress.org that it was `Tested up to: 6.1.1`.

I've dug further down the source code to the last [commit of the plugin files](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/2840306/category-posts/tags/4.9.13/readme.txt), and you can see that the change was only made on the `readme.txt` file and it's just the `Tested up to: 6.1` part:

[image: plugin file changes]

WordPress.org's plugin listing page is generated from this `readme.txt` file. So what WordPress.org is referring to when it says: `Last updated: 1 month ago`, is only this much.

So you see, there's no significant update and there's no actual disagreement about the update date.

Comment: That is a very helpful clarification between what I assumed Last Updated means and what it actually does.

Comment: In a way, this makes sense. Because there are many plugins that don't need to be updated. However, users still need to know, up to what WordPress version the plugin is tested to work without issues.